# How to run training with pre-made dense layers in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am in the process of re-writing code that is compatible with TF 2.0. Unfortunately, almost every example provided by the website uses the keras API. I, however, want to write code with raw tensorflow functions.

At some point, the new way of calculating and applying gradients during the training process looks something like this (code stolen from [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/tensorflow_v2/notebooks/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.ipynb)):

```
# Optimization process. 
def run_optimization(x, y):
    # Wrap computation inside a GradientTape for automatic differentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        pred = logistic_regression(x)
        loss = cross_entropy(pred, y)

    # Compute gradients.
    gradients = g.gradient(loss, [W, b])

    # Update W and b following gradients.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [W, b]))
```

The thing that causes problems here is the fact that I have to specify the trainable variables. In this particular case, it is easy because W and b have been created manually. It's also easy when using a keras model through the use of `model.trainable_variables`.

In my model, I am using dense layers provided by tensorflow, e.g. `tf.keras.layers.Dense`. The function provided in tensorflow 1.x for this usecase was `tf.trainable_variables()`, but it does not exist anymore.

How do I access their internal weights to pass them to the GradientTape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Keras layers have a property `trainable_variables` which you can use to access them. There's also `trainable_weights` but in most cases the two are identical. Note that this will actually be an empty list until the layer has been built, which you can do by calling `layer.build(input_shape)`. Alternatively, a layer will be built the first time it is called on an input.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it sound a bit like a hack. I will try it though, don't get me wrong. Do you have, by chance, any examples/sources on how to write clean, non-keras code?

Comment: I don't get how this is a "hack". In TF2.0 there are no more "global collections" that keep track of variables in the background, and so there is no simple way to get all variables in one line. If you want such a feature but also have low-level control, you might need to write your own wrappers. Or consider using Keras' "model subclassing" approach where you also have very fine control over what the model does while retaining the advantage of accessing `model.trainable_variables` etc.

Comment: I managed to train my model utilizing the subclassing approach. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have an equivalent of the `tf.trainable_variables()` in Keras, which is [`tf.keras.layers.Layer.trainable_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#trainable_variables).

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#part_ii_writing_your_own_training_evaluation_loops_from_scratch) is a more real example on how to use gradient tape with Keras model.

Comment: Thank you. The keras layer was more of an example. If possible, could you provide a source of non-keras models with standard layers?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-keras models"? From what I understand, in TF2.0 there is only "Keras models" or "Estimators". But Keras models is the recommended way to build/train/use new models.

Comment: By this I mean to use only the low-level tensorflow API. According to [this google dev talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEljKc9ZtU8), it should absolutely be possible. It is in fact recommended to use the high-level API keras, but for my project I need more control, thus the non-keras approach.